# $uibModal backdrop false not working

Tags: css, angularjs

Need a semi transparent background outside the modal area.W hat I get is Opaque white area.Tried setting backdrop:false dint work.

```
    var confirmInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
    templateUrl: 'abc.html',
    size: 'sm',
    backdrop: false,
    controller:function($uibModalInstance){
                this.cancel = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
                this.ok=function(){
                }
    },
    controllerAs:'$ctrl',
    resolve: {
                items: function () {
                console.log("In resolve");
            }
    }
    });
```

Below is my Html code for modal:

```
    <div><h1>Welcome here.. doing some more displaying stuff</h1></div>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="abc.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
            Remove {{$ctrl.type}}
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
               <p>Confirm request for removal of {{$ctrl.type}} {{$ctrl.name}}?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn-revoke" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Ok</button>
                <button class="btn-cancel" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: works fine in demo site so create a plunker that reproduces problem. See [mcve]

Comment: Yes the same example works fine in plunker. So why not here.

Comment: you must have different css , or a css conflict. Need to inspect the rules that apply to overlay in your browser devt tools elemetns inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove backdrop: false. Because the default behaviour is to show semi-transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is a CSS property called "opacity", you have only to create a class with this and add the class to the desired element:

```
.className {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Opacity setted at 0.5 will make the element semi transparent, so you can still appreciate it yet you can see through it.

For further documentation here you have the official site: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Hope it helps!

Comment: so where should I add here, can you demonstrate.